# VSCode CMake Tools disabling "Configure On Open" doesn't seem to be working

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, settings

I have a workspace with several folders in it, one of which is a C++ folder with CMake stuff in it, but the others don't (they're Python or text folders). Since recently, when I open the workspace, CMake always tries and fails to configure every folder, with causes the console to open annoyingly every time, displaying messages like `Cannot find CMT for folder [...] or we don't have an extension manager created yet. Setting feature set view to "full"`, and `Unable to determine what CMake generator to use. Please install or configure a preferred generator, or update settings.json, your Kit configuration or PATH variable. Error: No usable generator found`. I don't want this, I don't want CMake Tools to try to be clever and start configuring stuff without me explicitly telling it to. I've opened the settings, and unchecked the option "Cmake: Configure On Open", and unchecked the option "Cmake: Configure On Edit". I've double-checked that I've done that in all of "User", "Workspace", and "Folder" settings. However, this doesn't seem to work, still, every time I open VSCode, it tries and fails to configure, and it opens up the annoying console and displays the annoying error messages. Oh and as a bonus, it periodically displays an annoying error message box at the botton-right. How do I fix this?

Comment: Ran into the same annoying problem for a large nested project where the unasked for reconfigure at startup really adds up. (Switching "on edit" option off works though at least.) Seems to be an open issue ([#588](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/588)) on Github, at least as of today.